# How to retrieve maximum timedeltas for columns whose names follow a pattern

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a pandas data frame like this:

```
ID    |date   |X     |date:1  |X:1    |date:11 |X:11 ...  |date:1295|X:1295
1     |2011-08|5     |2011-09 |7      |No      |No   ...  |No       |No
2     |2011-10|5     |2011-12 |7      |2011-12 |21   ...  |No       |No
3     |2011-09|5     |2011-09 |7      |2012-01 |5    ...  |2017-11  |25
4     |2015-08|5     |No      |No     |No      |No   ...  |No       |No
```

QUESTION: How can I extract the maximum length of time that exists in each row?

In the example above, the desirable output could be:

```
ID    |delta_date 
1     |1
2     |2
3     |74
4     |0
```

(date measurement unit doesn't matter. it can be days, hours, etc., but for the sake of example, I have chosen month)

Assumption 1: the headings naming follow this pattern: `date, date:1, date1x  (0< x <296)`. for example: `date, date:1, date:11, date:12, ..., date:19, date:110,...,date:119,...,date:1295`

Assumption 2: ALL `date` columns contain either a value of `datetime` format or a filler `No`.

Assumption 3: `date:1295` is the highest number. In other words, the maximum number of cells to be compared in a row is 296.

Comment: are the date in increasing on the same row, like `date` will always be lower or equal than `date:1` etc?

Comment: yes. that's correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the dates are increasing on the same row:

You can try to select only the date column with [`filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html?highlight=filter#pandas.DataFrame.filter), use [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html#pandas.DataFrame.mask) to replace the No by Nan, `ffill` along the columns to get the last valid date per row on the last column that you select before subtracting the first column like to it. Add this as a column to your `df`:

```
df['delta_date'] = df.filter(like='date')\
                     .mask(df.filter(like='date').eq('No'))\
                     .ffill(axis=1)['date:1295']\
                   - df['date']
```

**EDIT**: in the case the date are not increasing on the same row, to get the maximum delta, you can do the difference between `max` and `min` per row once change the No with Nan:

```
df_date = df.filter(like='date').mask(df.filter(like='date').eq('No'))
df['delta_date'] = df_date.max(axis=1) - df_date.min(axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks! This is a neat solution. What if the date was not increasing?

Comment: @Pie-ton you could consider using the methods `min` and `max`. like `df_date = df.filter(like='date').mask(df.filter(like='date').eq('No'))` and then `df['delta_date'] = df_date.max(axis=1) - df_date.min(axis=1)` or something like that